# centos upgrade openssl - CVE-2016-0800 - drown attack

Tags: security, centos, updates, openssl, packages

Because of recent vulnerabilities discovered in old openssl versions I have to upgrade it.

But there is no current Version in the Centos Repositories... Is there a trustworthy repository out there which I can add and upgrade from?

Need current version of openssl 1.0.1. I think it is **1.0.1e_42.el6_7.4** (for CENTOS 6) as stated here: https://www.linuxos.pro/drown-attack-cve-2016-0800/.

Is there a way to safely upgrade (I don't want to mess around with making/compiling stuff and manually have to upgrade it).

Do I have to update configs of services like apache, postfix, etc. too?

Answer (score 2):

CentOS packages are rebuilt from the sources of Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  Red Hat [backports security fixes](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting) to their packages, meaning that although the version appears old, it is patched to fix security vulnerabilities.  For instance, specifically for the CVE you are concerned about, links to the security errata can be found [here](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2016-0800).  If you follow the links there, you will discover that openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4 has been patched for CVE-2016-0800.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I looked up vulnerable servers at drownattack.com.

I saw the vulnerable ports - POP3, IMAP, 443, etc.
Now I updated to latest available openssl via "yum update" - which is already patched (according to https://www.linuxos.pro/drown-attack-cve-2016-0800/):
"openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4".

To disable sslv2 on my services (apache & postfix) - just in case:

I edited configs for httpd (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf) and uncommented line "#SSLProtocols..." and edited it:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

test it (after restarting apache):

```
openssl s_client -ssl2 -connect www.example.com:443
```

got:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140313005905736:error:1407F0E5:SSL routines:SSL2_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s2_pkt.c:429:
```

so it is disabled.
Now postfix:
Edited /etc/postfix/main.cf and added at the bottom:

```
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
```

tested it (after restarting postfix, e.g. POP3):

```
openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:110 -starttls pop3 -ssl2
```

got

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140110128891720:error:1407F0E5:SSL routines:SSL2_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s2_pkt.c:429:
```

and it is disabled too.

Answer (score 0):

For those worried about Qualys SSLLabs certificate test giving a grade/rating lower than "A" due to DROWN and POODLE, these links give the best way to go about this:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1232413

and

https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2013/03/19/rc4-in-tls-is-broken-now-what#comment-8643

I had this issue with our EC2 instances and with some good support from AWS techs, I found that you have to include all the SSL config directives in **each VirtualHost directive** for it to work properly.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot ...
    ServerName ...
    ServerAlias ...
    SSLEngine ON
    SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM \
        EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 \
        EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 \
        EECDH EDH+aRSA \
        !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/...
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/...
    ErrorLog logs/...
    CustomLog logs/... combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The SSLCipherSuite value above should probably be changed whenever new vulnerabilities are found or if you think some ciphers are weak etc.

Regularly testing your SSL setup is a good idea.

EDIT: this is in addition to upgrading the openssl library to 1.0.1e_42.el6_7.4 (for CENTOS 6)